# tee command creates empty file

Tags: bash, list, loops, tee

I have the following list of stocks that is generated and it is placed in file called `awk_1`

```
dfs
fsd
dsf
sdf
```

I then run the following one liner which generates the correct ULR links

```
while read i ; do 
  echo $(http://uk.finance.yahoo.com/echartss=$i#symbol=$i\;range=my\;compare=\;indicator=volume\;charttype\=area\;crosshair\=on\;ohlcvalues\=0\;logscale\=off\;source\=undefined\;) tee stock_urls; 
done < awk_1
```

However is does not put the output in the file called `stock_urls`?

Also it generate and strange output on the screen,  below is a small section of the output that I get to standard output. It puts `./large_cap_stocks.sh: 51: ./large_cap_stocks.sh:` at the front and `not found` at the end; why might that be happening?

I have searching high and low for why this is not working - any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to use $( ) as quotes?  You appear to be trying to run a URL as a command.  And if you want the output of echo to be the input for tee you would need a pipe.

Comment: @user1380599 Keep the block of code and input file 4 spaces from the start of the line (select all of the code and press `{}`), so it appears as code, otherwise formatting gets broken and the code is virtually unreadable (hard to read as is)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably meant to write like this:

```
while read i; do
    echo "http://uk.finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=$i#symbol=$i\;range=my\;compare=\;indicator=volume\;charttype\=area\;crosshair\=on\;ohlcvalues\=0\;logscale\=off\;source\=undefined\;"
done < awk_1 | tee stock_urls
```

That is:

- In the `echo` command, use `"..."` to quote your text instead of `$(...)` which is something else
- Use the pipe operator `|` to pass the output to `tee`, and you can pipe the entire loop this way, no need to do for individual `echo` lines.

Comment: Change `|` to `|&` (bash 4+) or `2>&1 |` if you want to store stderr as well (no idea if user does in this case, but might be useful).

Comment: @user1380599 Click the check mark by the answer so it's marked as solved if this answer fixed your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As for what's wrong, you have several basic syntax errors here.

- `echo $(http://something)` attempts to run `http://something` as a command, and then pass its output as a string to `echo`. Of course, in your case, `http://something` is not a valid command, so that's why you get the `not found` error message.

  - ... This is a [useless use of `echo`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo), anyway.
- `echo $(http://something) tee file` is passing three arguments to `echo`; two of them are `tee` and `file`, so it will not actually run `tee` at all.
- If you fixed that, running `tee` again and again inside the loop would overwrite the output file in each iteration, ending up with only the output from the last loop iteration in the file.
- Tangentially, the superstitious backslashing in the `echo` argument is superfluous. The equals sign is not a shell metacharacter at all, and a semicolon inside a double-quoted string only represents the literal semicolon character itself.

A minimal fix would look like

```
while read i ; do 
    echo "http://uk.finance.yahoo.com/echartss=$i#symbol=$i;range=my;compare=;indicator=volume;charttype=area;crosshair=on;ohlcvalues=0;logscale=off;source=undefined;" |
     tee -a stock_urls
done < awk_1
```

but a better fix would avoid redirecting from inside the loop;

```
while read i ; do 
    echo "http://uk.finance.yahoo.com/echartss=$i#symbol=$i;range=my;compare=;indicator=volume;charttype=area;crosshair=on;ohlcvalues=0;logscale=off;source=undefined;"
done < awk_1 | tee stock_urls
```

and a better solution still would be to replace this gnarly [and slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762625/bash-while-read-loop-extremely-slow-compared-to-cat-why) loop with a one-liner (or, well, two-liner);

```
sed 's|.*|http://uk.finance.yahoo.com/echartss=&#symbol=&;range=my;compare=;indicator=volume;charttype=area;crosshair=on;ohlcvalues=0;logscale=off;source=undefined;|' awk_1 |
tee stock_urls
```

This uses the `sed` command `s/regex/replacement/` where the regex matches the entire input line, and `&` in the replacement recalls the text which the regex matched.

Perhaps also visit https://shellcheck.net/ which should be able to point out at least some of these errors.