# Change one line to column

Tags: sh

I have a file like this:

```
20180127200000
DEFAULT, Proc_m0_s1 
DEFAULT, Proc_m0_s2
DEFAULT, Proc_m0_s3
20180127200001
DEFAULT, Proc_m0_s1 
DEFAULT, Proc_m0_s2
DEFAULT, Proc_m0_s3
```

I'd like to convert to:

```
20180127200000 DEFAULT, Proc_m0_s1 
20180127200000 DEFAULT, Proc_m0_s2
20180127200000 DEFAULT, Proc_m0_s3
20180127200001 DEFAULT, Proc_m0_s1 
20180127200001 DEFAULT, Proc_m0_s2
20180127200001 DEFAULT, Proc_m0_s3
```

The time stamp appears every 4 lines.

Comment: Not quite sure your question is really clear here.  You have a data set but nothing of what you've done or are really trying to do.  If you're trying to get the values from one line into a row you should split the one line up in a loop.  This looks like it is comma separated so just loop, split on the comma and move it into an array.  Then parse out the array.

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
iconvert() {
    while true; do
        read linePrefix || return 0
        for i in $(seq $((prefix_lines - 1))); do
            read line || return 0
            echo "$linePrefix" "$line"
        done
    done
}
```

You just call `iconvert` like this:

```
prefix_lines=4
iconvert < file.txt
```

which gives your desired output.

Comment: You probably want to avoid the horrible overhead of a `while read -r` loop (and even more a `while true; read` without `-r`). This should be basically a one-liner with Awk.

Comment: @tripleee Not sure about that. What exactly is it?

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762625/bash-while-read-line-extremely-slow-compared-to-cat-why

Comment: @tripleee Problem is, I don't know `awk` :(

Answer (score 1):

Awk should be both faster and simpler than a shell loop for this type of task.

```
awk 'NR%4==1 { time=$1; next }
    { print time " " $0 }' file
```

`NR` is the line number. If the line number modulo 4 is one, remember the first field but don't print. Otherwise, print with the remembered value and a space as the prefix.

Comment: Good spot. TIL.