# Converting string to integer in Linux using shell

Tags: shell

I am trying to read file which contains value "0" which is enclosed in double quotes. After this I need to perform decision based on the value like

```
while read line;do result=$line;done < File.csv
if [ $result -gt 0 ]

then
       echo "Failed"
fi
```

Now this is giving me error like integer expected. Please help.

Comment: You could find libraries in C++ or Python parsing CSV files. Why don't you use one of them? And at least, specify in [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) notation the syntax of valid input. Consider also using [GNU gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) or [GNU guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) for that, since CSV files are ill defined.

Comment: It's not clear why you are comparing `fresult` instead of `result`; is that just a typo, or do you hope for `fresult` to magically contain something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux is a kernel. The script you show is a shell script.

In the Bourne family of shells, all atomic variables are strings. (In Bash / ksh / etc there are also arrays which are collections of strings.)

To strip quotes from both sides of a string, try this sequence of [parameter expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```sh
value=${value%\"}
value=${value#\"}
```

Using shell built-ins will be a lot quicker than using an external process, though each of these should be fairly obvious if you had googled at all before asking:

```
value=$(echo "$value" | tr -d '"')            # discards " everywhere
value=$(sed 's/^"\(.*\)"$/\1/' <<<"$value")   # Bash specific <<<here string
value=$(awk -v val="$value" 'BEGIN { sub(/^"/, "", val); sub(/"$/, "", val); print val }')
```

Your loop will read and discard all values in the file, then process whatever was on the last line of the file. I'm guessing you want to process each value *inside*  the loop instead?

```sh
while IFS="" read -r line; do
    result=${line%\"}
    result=${result#\"}
    [ $result -gt 0 ] && { echo "Failed" >&2; exit 1; }
done < File.csv
```

(notice `IFS=""` and `read -r`, and printing the error message to standard error instead of standard output) but a *much* better solution is to use Awk for this (the shell's `while read -r` is [horribly inefficient and usually wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762625/bash-while-read-loop-extremely-slow-compared-to-cat-why));

```sh
awk '{ sub(/^"/, ""); sub(/"$/, "");
    if (0+$0 > 1) { print "Failed" >>"/dev/stderr"; exit 1 } }' File.csv
```

Comment: Thanks using below resolved the issue
value=${value%\"}
value=${value#\"}

Comment: Thanks for the accept, though perhaps it would be better if you unaccept so that this question can be deleted as a redundant duplicate.