# Substringing with bash

Tags: bash, substring

I am trying to substring many strings with bash.However, despite the prefix is sorrectly deleted, the suffix is not.

One of the strings:

```
lcl|MK087647.1_cds_QHD46953.1_7_[gene=rpl2]_[protein=ribosomal_protein_L2]_[exception=RNA_editing]_[protein_id=QHD46953.1]_[location=complement(71768..73444)]_[gbkey=CDS]
```

The desired output:

```
MK087647.1_cds_QHD46953.1_7_[gene=rpl2]_[protein=ribosomal_protein_L2]
```

The code

```
 for row in $colonna2; do tmp=${row#*lcl|}
 colonna2_newname=${tmp%exception=*} echo $colonna2_newname; done
```

The output

```
MK087647.1_cds_QHD46953.1_7_[gene=rpl2]_[protein=ribosomal_protein_L2]_[exception=RNA_editing]_[protein_id=QHD46953.1]_[location=complement(71768..73444)]_[gbkey=CDS]
```

Any guess why the suffix is not deleted? Has my syntax some error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't reproduce this, perhaps also because we don't know what `colonna2` contains. If you are reading a file, try `sed 's/.*lcl|\(.*\)exception=/\1/'`

Comment: If you genuinely don't have a newline or a semicolon before the `echo`, the line gets parsed before the variable is set.

Answer (score 1):

You have the variable substitution mostly right; it seems the main problem with the code is that there is no line break or semicolon after you define the `colonna2_newname` variable.

You will also want to change the `colonna2_newname` variable's definition from `${tmp%exception=*}` to `${tmp%_[exception=*}`.

```
for row in $colonna2
do
  tmp="${row#*lcl|}"
  colonna2_newname="${tmp%exception=*}"
  echo "$colonna2_newname"
done

# output:
# MK087647.1_cds_QHD46953.1_7_[gene=rpl2]_[protein=ribosomal_protein_L2]
```

Now about the `for` loop: If any of the lines in your `$colonna2` variable have whitespace in them, `for` will split the line into separate strings after each space. `for` loops are better suited for use with arrays and globbed filenames/pathnames. `while read` loops are better to use with lines of text:

```
while IFS=$'\n' read -r row
do
  tmp="${row#*lcl|}"
  colonna2_newname="${tmp%exception=*}"
  echo "$colonna2_newname"
done <<< $colonna2
```

Comment: The `while read` is an improvement over [reading lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) which is inherently broken, but it is also rather suboptimal; see [`while read` loop extremely slow compared to `cat`, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762625/bash-while-read-loop-extremely-slow-compared-to-cat-why)