# read file line by line and sum each line individually

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, git-bash, bash-completion

Im trying to make a script that creates a file say file01.txt that writes a number on each line.

```
001
002
...
998
999
```

then I want to read the file line by line and sum each line and say whether the number is even or odd.
sum each line like 0+0+1 = 1 which is odd
9+9+8 = 26 so even

```
001 odd
002 even
..
998 even
999 odd
```

I tried

```
while IFS=read -r line; do sum+=line >> file02.txt; done <file01.txt
```

but that sums the whole file not each line.

Comment: What is the difference between `sum each line` and `sum the whole file`?

Comment: @rowboat split the number into each digit and sum it then modulus to check even or odd, not sure how to implement it into a loop tho

Comment: @rowboat sorry i didnt explain that part, just edited, I want to check whether sum is even or odd, so 011 would be 0+1+1 = 2 so even

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this fairly easily in bash itself making use of built-in parameter expansions to trim leading zeros from the beginning of each line in order to sum the digits for odd / even.

When reading from a file (either a named file or `stdin` by default), you can use the initialization with default to use the first argument (positional parameter) as the filename (if given) and if not, just read from `stdin`, e.g.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

infile="${1:-/dev/stdin}"     ## read from file provide as $1 or stdin
```

Which you will use `infile` with your `while` loop, e.g.

```sh
while read -r line; do        ## loop reading each line
  ...
done < "$infile"
```

To trim the leading zeros, first obtain the substring of leading zeros trimming all digits from the right until only zeros remain, e.g.

```sh
  leading="${line%%[1-9]*}"                         ## get leading 0's
```

Now using the same type parameter expansion with `#` instead of `%%` trim the leading zeros substring from the front of `line` saving the resulting number in `value`, e.g.

```sh
  value="${line#$leading}"                          ## trim from front
```

Now zero your `sum` and loop over the digits in `value` to obtain the sum of digits:

```sh
  for ((i=0;i<${#value};i++)); do                   ## loop summing digits
    sum=$((sum + ${value:$i:1}))
  done
```

All that remains is your even / odd test. Putting it altogether in a short example script that intentionally outputs the sum of digits in addition to your wanted `"odd"` / `"even"` output, you could do:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

infile="${1:-/dev/stdin}"     ## read from file provide as $1 or stdin

while read -r line; do                              ## read each line
  [ "$line" -eq "$line" 2>/dev/null ] || continue   ## validate integer
  
  leading="${line%%[1-9]*}"                         ## get leading 0's
  value="${line#$leading}"                          ## trim from front
  sum=0                                             ## zero sum
  
  for ((i=0;i<${#value};i++)); do                   ## loop summing digits
    sum=$((sum + ${value:$i:1}))
  done
  
  printf "%s (sum=%d) - " "$line" "$sum"            ## output line w/sum
                                                    ## (temporary output)
  if ((sum % 2 == 0)); then                         ## check odd / even
    echo "even"
  else
    echo "odd"
  fi
done < "$infile"
```

(**note:** you can actually loop over the digits in `line` and skip removing the leading zeros substring. The removal ensure that if the whole value is used it isn't interpreted as an octal value -- up to you)

**Example Use/Output**

Using a quick process substitution to provide input of `001 - 020` on `stdin` you could do:

```
$ ./sumdigitsoddeven.sh < <(printf "%03d\n" {1..20})
001 (sum=1) - odd
002 (sum=2) - even
003 (sum=3) - odd
004 (sum=4) - even
005 (sum=5) - odd
006 (sum=6) - even
007 (sum=7) - odd
008 (sum=8) - even
009 (sum=9) - odd
010 (sum=1) - odd
011 (sum=2) - even
012 (sum=3) - odd
013 (sum=4) - even
014 (sum=5) - odd
015 (sum=6) - even
016 (sum=7) - odd
017 (sum=8) - even
018 (sum=9) - odd
019 (sum=10) - even
020 (sum=2) - even
```

You can simply remove the output of `"(sum=X)"` when you have confirmed it operates as you expect and redirect the output to your new file. Let me know if I understood your question properly and if you have further questions.

Comment: Yes, thank you this is perfect. I was trying to do it myself and got stuck on the summing and didn't think of getting rid of the zeroes.

Comment: See my note, you don't actually have to get rid of the zeros, because adding `0` to the sum won't matter, but if you try and use the value alone, values with a leading zero will be interpreted as an *octal* value. You can `for ((i=0;i<${#line };i++)); do sum=$((sum + ${line:$i:1})); done` and get rid of `leading` and `value` variables -- up to you. Good luck with your scripting.

Comment: Also note, if you have a few thousand lines of input, then a shell script is fine, but if you have a few million lines, `awk` will be orders of magnitude faster. Bash is incredibly capable at processing text, but isn't the fastest way to process text. `awk` is the Swiss Army-Knife of text processing. If you haven't made friends with it yet, it should be next on your list of tools to master. Then `sed`. Another benefit of `awk` is it will handle floating-point math -- something bash can't (without a separate utility like `bc` or `calc`)

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk:

```
awk -vFS='' '{sum=0; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) sum+=$i;
              print $0, sum%2 ? "odd" : "even"}' file01.txt
```

The `FS` awk variable defines the field separator. If it is set to the empty string (this is what the `-vFS=''` option does) then each character is a separate field.

The rest is trivial: the block between curly braces is executed for each line of the input. It compute the sum of the fields with a for `loop` (`NF` is another awk variable, its value is the number of fields of the current record). And it then prints the original line (`$0`) followed by the string `even` if the sum is even, else `odd`.

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the bash version:

```
parity=("even" "odd")
while IFS= read -r line; do
    mapfile -t ary < <(fold -w1 <<< "$line")
    sum=0
    for i in "${ary[@]}"; do
        (( sum += i ))
    done
    echo "$line" "${parity[sum % 2]}"
done < file01.txt > file92.txt
```

- `fold -w1 <<< "$line"` breaks the string `$line` into lines of character
  (one digit per line).
- `mapfile` assigns `array` to the elements fed by the `fold` command.

Please note the bash script is not efficient in time and not suitable
for the large inputs.

Answer (score 0):

**pure awk:**

```
BEGIN {
    for (i=1; i<=999; i++) {
        printf ("%03d\n", i) > ARGV[1]
    }
    close(ARGV[1])

    ARGC = 2
    FS = ""

    result[0] = "even"
    result[1] = "odd"
}

{
    printf("%s: %s\n", $0, result[($1+$2+$3) % 2])
}
```

Processing a file line by line, and doing math, is a perfect task for `awk`.

**pure bash:**

```
set -e

printf '%03d\n' {1..999} > "${1:?no path provided}"

result=(even odd)

mapfile -t num_list < "$1"

for i in "${num_list[@]}"; do
    echo $i: ${result[(${i:0:1} + ${i:1:1} + ${i:2:1}) % 2]}
done
```

A similar method can be applied in `bash`, but it's slower.

**comparison:**

`bash` is about 10x slower.

```
$ cd ./tmp.Kb5ug7tQTi

$ bash -c 'time awk -f ../solution.awk numlist-awk > result-awk'

real    0m0.108s
user    0m0.102s
sys 0m0.000s

$ bash -c 'time bash ../solution.bash numlist-bash > result-bash'

real    0m0.931s
user    0m0.929s
sys 0m0.000s

$ diff --report-identical result*
Files result-awk and result-bash are identical

$ diff --report-identical numlist*
Files numlist-awk and numlist-bash are identical

$ head -n 5 *
==> numlist-awk <==
001
002
003
004
005

==> numlist-bash <==
001
002
003
004
005

==> result-awk <==
001: odd
002: even
003: odd
004: even
005: odd

==> result-bash <==
001: odd
002: even
003: odd
004: even
005: odd
```

- `read` is a bottleneck in a `while IFS= read -r line` loop. More info in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762625/bash-while-read-loop-extremely-slow-compared-to-cat-why).
- `mapfile` (combined with `for` loop) can be slightly faster, but still slow (it also copies all the data to an array first).
- Both solutions create a number list in a new file (which was in the question), and print the odd/even results to `stdout`. The path for the file is given as a single argument.
- In `awk`, you can set the field separator to empty (`FS=""`) to process individual characters.
- In `bash` it can be done with substring expansion (`${var:index:length}`).
- Modulo 2 (`number % 2`) to get odd or even.