# replace elements in csv with bash

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I want to replace some values with bash in a csv file like this:

```
age,sex,bmi,smoker,region,charges
19,female,27.9,yes,southwest,16884.924
23,male,29.83,no,northeast,1725.5523
```

Basically, I need to replace the binary fields with 0 or 1 values. My code is the following:

```
filename="$1"
IFS=,
while read -ra values; do
 
  case "${values[1]}" in
  male)    values[1]=0 ;;
  female)  values[1]=1 ;;
  esac
  
  case "${values[4]}" in
  yes) values[4]=1 ;;
  no)  values[4]=0 ;;
  esac
    
done
} < $filename
```

I am executing the script with the calling:

```
./b.sh insurance.csv
```

I don't know what I have wrong but the csv does not update with the new values.

Comment: Please add sample input **with correct field separator** (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output **with correct field separator** for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Please add your shebang to your code.

Comment: `IFS=,` says to treat the comma as the input field delimiter but there are no commas in the sample input file you've provided hence the entire line is read into `values[0]`; it's not clear (to us) where there's a disconnect ... is your input file a real `.csv` (ie, fields are comma separated) or are the fields really delimited by a variable number of spaces (as in the provided sample); please update the question to clarify the contents of the actual file (eg, `head -5 filename`)

Answer (score 0):

You are just reading and discarding the values in the file, not saving them.

Anyway, a much better solution is to rewrite this as an Awk script.

```
awk -F, 'FNR > 1 { $2 = ($2 == "female")
  $4 = ($4 == "yes) }1' "$1" >"$1.tmp" &&
mv "$1.tmp" "$1"
```

The static temp file is a security problem; use `mktemp` for any production script. The same mechanism would work for your original attempt, too; print to a new file, then move the file back to replace the original.

See also [Bash `while read` loop extremely slow compared to `cat`, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762625/bash-while-read-loop-extremely-slow-compared-to-cat-why) as well as [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: GNU Awk has the capability to write changes back to the same file; see the `-i inplace` option.

Comment: This assumes your file is really a CSV file (comma-separated values); if your real file uses a different format, maybe try a different value for the `-F` option, or in the worst case a different tool.