# Linux shell script to read from a file with separator and then manipulate some fields and redirect with updated fields in new file

Tags: linux, string, file

Need to read line by line a file example below and then get only  and put it in separate file
file 1

```
1~abc~select col1,col2,col3,col4 from <tablename> where <condition> group by~xyz
2~abc~select col1,col2,col3      from <tablename> where <condition> group by~xyq
3~abc~select col1,col2           from <tablename> where <condition> group by~xyg
```

new file expecting

```
1~abc~<condition>~xyz
2~abc~<condition>~xyq
3~abc~<condition>~xyg
```

is there any simpler way to get this done using shell script.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using **sed** utility in unix. A single expression is sufficient actually `sed -e 's/select .* where //;s/ group by.*~/~/'`

See it in action here:

```
pankaj@pankaj-mac TP % cat inputfile.txt 
1~abc~select col1,col2,col3,col4 from <tablename> where <condition> group by~xyz
2~abc~select col1,col2,col3      from <tablename> where <condition> group by~xyq
3~abc~select col1,col2           from <tablename> where <condition> group by~xyg

pankaj@pankaj-mac TP % sed -e 's/select .* where //;s/ group by//' inputfile.txt > newfile.txt
pankaj@pankaj-mac TP % cat newfile.txt 
1~abc~<condition>~xyz
2~abc~<condition>~xyq
3~abc~<condition>~xyg

pankaj@pankaj-mac TP %
```

Comment: You might want to use a single regex with a back reference. Perhaps prefer `[^~]` to avoid letting the match straddle field boundaries. `sed 's/select [^~]* where \([^~]*\) group by[^~]*/\1/'`

Comment: I tried Pankaj Saini solution and it worked thanks a lot for your time and effort

Comment: One additional stuff , how about if group by , order by have values as shown below.
forgot to add in previous one 

1~abc~select col1,col2,col3,col4 from <tablename> where <condition> group by col1,col2,col3,col4 order by col1,col2,col3,col4~xyz
2~abc~select col1,col2,col3      from <tablename> where <condition> group by   col1,col2,col3 order by  col1,col2,col3~xyq
3~abc~select col1,col2           from <tablename> where <condition> group by col1,col2 order by col1,col2~xyg

Need output like 
1~abc~<condition>~xyz
2~abc~<condition>~xyq
3~abc~<condition>~xyg

Comment: Edit my response based on this additional input. Also the solution proposed by tripleee will work..

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU Awk

```
$ awk -F'~| where | group ' '$0=$1"~"$2"~"$4"~"$NF' file 
$ awk -F'~| where | group ' -v OFS='~' '{print $1,$2,$4,$NF}' file
$ awk -F '~' -v OFS='~' 'gsub(/.* where | group by.*/,"",$3)' file
$ awk '$0=gensub(/(.*)select .* where (.*) group by(.*)/,"\\1\\2\\3",1)' file
$ awk 'match($0,/(.*)select.*where (.*) group by(.*)/,a){$0=a[1]a[2]a[3]}1' file 

1~abc~<condition>~xyz
2~abc~<condition>~xyq
3~abc~<condition>~xyg
```

Answer (score -1):

In the slightly more general case where the regexes could also match within some of the other fields, Awk might be a better choice than `sed`.

```
awk -F '~' '{
  sub(/.* where /, "", $3);
  sub(/ group by.*/, "", $3)
 }1' file >newfile
```

The final `1` is the common Awk idiom for "print the current input unconditionally".

This could also be accomplished with a `while read -r` loop in the shell, but you generally want to avoid that; see [Bash `while read` loop extremely slow compared to `cat`, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762625/bash-while-read-loop-extremely-slow-compared-to-cat-why)