# Grep a line from a file and replace a substring and append the line to the original file in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

This is what I want to do.

for example my file contains many lines say :

```
ABC,2,4
DEF,5,6
GHI,8,9
```

I want to copy the second line and replace a substring EF(all occurrences) and make it XY and add this line back to the file so the file looks like this:

```
ABC,2,4
DEF,5,6
GHI,8,9
DXY,5,6
```

how can I achieve this in bash?

EDIT : I want to do this in general and not necessarily for the second line. I want to grep EF, and do the substition in whatever line is returned.

Comment: `printf '%s\n' '$kx' "g/^.*EF.*,.*/t'x" "'x+;\$s/EF/XY/" ,p Q | ed -s file.txt`

Comment: So if you have another line `EFZ,3,7` you want to append `XYZ,3,7` to the end as well?

Comment: yes all lines, @DavidC.Rankin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple Awk script.

```
awk -F, -v pat="EF" -v rep="XY" 'BEGIN { OFS=FS }
  $1 ~ pat { x = $1; sub(pat, rep, x); y = $0; sub($1, x, y); a[++n] = y }
  1
  END { for(i=1; i<=n; i++) print a[i] }' file
```

The `-F ,` says to use comma as the input field separator (internal variable `FS`) and in the `BEGIN` block, we also set that as the output field separator (`OFS`).

If the first field matches the pattern, we copy the first field into `x`, substitute `pat` with `rep`, and then substitute the first field of the whole line `$0` with the new result, and append it to the array `a`.

`1` is a shorthand to say "print the current input line".

Finally, in the `END` block, we output the values we have collected into `a`.

This could be somewhat simplified by hardcoding the pattern and the replacement, but I figured it's more useful to make it modular so that you can plug in whatever values you need.

While this all could be done in native Bash, it tends to get a bit tortured; spending the 30 minutes or so that it takes to get a basic understanding of Awk will be well worth your time. Perhaps tangentially see also [`while read` loop extremely slow compared to `cat`, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762625/bash-while-read-loop-extremely-slow-compared-to-cat-why) which explains part of the rationale for preferring to use an external tool like Awk over a pure Bash solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sed` command:

```
sed '
/EF/H # copy all matching lines
${    # on the last line
  p   # print it
  g   # paste the copied lines
  s/EF/XY/g # replace all occurences
  s/^\n//   # get rid of the extra newline
}'
```

As a one-liner:

```
sed '/EF/H;${p;g;s/EF/XY/g;s/^\n//}' file.csv
```

Comment: what if it's not necessarily on the second line? I want to just grep the substring EF and do the substitution with whatever line is returned

Comment: I tried using sed with pipe but doesn;t seem to work

Comment: also this seems to only replace first ocurrance of EF, I want to replace all ocurrances of EF with XY

Comment: You need to change `/EF/h` (copy) to `/EF/H` (append) in your first commented expression to match what you have in the one-liner `:)`

Answer (score 0):

If `ed` is available/acceptable, something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

ed -s file.txt <<-'EOF'
  $kx
  g/^.*EF.*,.*/t'x
  'x+;$s/EF/XY/
  ,p
  Q
EOF
```

Or in one-line.

```
printf '%s\n' '$kx' "g/^.*EF.*,.*/t'x" "'x+;\$s/EF/XY/" ,p Q | ed -s file.txt
```

---

- Change `Q` to `w` if *in-place* editing is needed.
- Remove the `,p` to silence the output.

Answer (score 0):

Using BASH:

```
#!/bin/bash

src="${1:-f.dat}"
rep="${2:-XY}"

declare -a new_lines
while read -r line ; do
  if [[ "$line" == *EF* ]] ; then
    new_lines+=("${line/EF/${rep}}")
  fi
done <"$src"

printf "%s\n" "${new_lines[@]}" >> "$src"
```

Contents of `f.dat` before:

```
ABC,2,4
DEF,5,6
GHI,8,9
```

Contents of `f.dat` after:

```
ABC,2,4
DEF,5,6
GHI,8,9
DXY,5,6
```

Answer (score 0):

Following on from the great answer by @tripleee, you can create a variation that uses a single call to `sub()` by outputting all records before the substitution is made, then add the updated record to the array to be output with the `END` rule, e.g.

```bash
awk -F, '1; /EF/ {sub(/EF/,"XY"); a[++n]=$0} END {for(i=1;i<=n;i++) print a[i]}' file
```

**Example Use/Output**

An expanded input based on your answer to my comment below the question that all occurrences of `EF` will be replaced with `XY` in all records, e.g.

```
$ cat file
ABC,2,4
DEF,5,6
GHI,8,9
EFZ,3,7
```

Use and output:

```
$ awk -F, '1; /EF/ {sub(/EF/,"XY"); a[++n]=$0} END {for(i=1;i<=n;i++) print a[i]}' file
ABC,2,4
DEF,5,6
GHI,8,9
EFZ,3,7
DXY,5,6
XYZ,3,7
```

Let me know if you have questions.