# how to pipe the stdout of one command into %- to remove the trailing dash in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have this command:

```
MODIFIED_BRANCH_NAME=$(echo $BRANCH_NAME | tr '/_.' '-' | tr -s '-' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' )
MODIFIED_BRANCH_NAME=${MODIFIED_BRANCH_NAME%-}
```

I want to do it one line. how can I pipe something into %- operator?

example input:

```
abc//kdkd_kdkd_-
```

expected:

```
abc-kdkd-kdkd
```

actually what I want to do is that after doing `$(echo $BRANCH_NAME | tr '/_.' '-' | tr -s '-' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' )` I want to remove the trailing "-" if existing

Comment: Any chance to have the raw output of `echo $branch_name` ?

Comment: @GillesQuénot do you mean an example? I added to the question

Comment: "how can I pipe something into %- operator" -- `%-` is not an operator, it's a [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) mechanism. You need to have a parameter to expand.

Comment: "I want it on one line", .... you can join the 2 lines and separate the cmds with `;`, ie.  `MODIFIED_BRANCH_NAME=$(echo $BRA .... ) ; MODIFIED_BRANCH_NAME=${MODIFIED_BRANCH_NAME%-}` . Good luck.

Comment: Why do you want to use `%-` for this part when you've used 3 pipes and 3 calls to `tr` for the rest of it? **WHAT** you're asking to do, `I want to remove the trailing "-" if existing`, is trivial but **HOW** you're asking to do it, `how can I pipe something into %-`, is impossible.

Comment: You can combine the first two `tr` commands: `tr -s '/_.' '-'`

Comment: The line `MODIFIED_BRANCH_NAME=${MODIFIED_BRANCH_NAME%-}` does not make sense. It sets the variable to the empty string, if it was empty or non-existent before. Since you already assigned to the variable just before, we know that it can't be non-existen, and the statement simply says:  _set the variable to empty if it is empty_, so in the end it is a no-op. What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

> how can I pipe something into %- operator?

you can't pipe something into an operator.  An operator works on a value, not a stream.

> remove the trailing dash in bash?

`sed` would be an easy way.  `sed 's/-$//g'` will replace a `-` ad the end (`$`).  Demo:

```
% sed s/-$//g <<<"hi-world-"
hi-world
```

So your new pipeline might look like:

```
MODIFIED_BRANCH_NAME=$(echo $BRANCH_NAME | tr '/_.' '-' | tr -s '-' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sed 's/-$//g' )
```

Or you could replace those commands with `sed` which can do most of them.

```
%# echo "Ji/wor..ld_" | sed -e s/[./_]/-/g -e 's/-\{2,\}/-/g' -e s/-$//g   | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]
ji-wor-ld
```

Comment: but it is using sed. I dont want to use sed. I want to use %- . The question is how to pipe to %-

Comment: is sed installed by default in all linux systems?

Comment: @AminBa --if  "I want to use %-"  then you can't do it in one line. if "I want to remove the trailing "-""  then one line is possible, but you need to be flexible about your constraints

Comment: `sed` is part of the base userland on any remotely Unix-like system, yes. By and large, any recent system will try to implement POSIX, or document how they deviated, and why.

Comment: If the question is "how to pipe to %-" and the only answer you'll accept is a way to pipe to %- then you may as well delete the question because you can't. If, on the other hand, you want a way to do what you need to do (as opposed to HOW you're trying to do it), then see the feedback you're getting in answers and comments.

Comment: Sed is pretty ubiquitous.  It's not guaranteed to be installed.  Neither is `tr`.  In situations like minimal docker environments both are simulated with busybox often.  So pretty likely to be available.

Comment: Don't forget the `sed` can also do transliterations, (transformations in `sed` speak) with the curiously named `y` cmd, i.e. `echo "Royal Nonesuch" | sed 'y/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/'` results in `royal nonesuch`. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 2):

All this can be done in one single `gnu-sed` command like this:

```bash
branch_name='abc//kdkd_kdKD_-'

sed -E 's#[/_.-]+#-#g; s/-$//; s/[A-Z]+/\L&/g' <<< "$branch_name"

abc-kdkd-kdkd
```

Here is the breakup:

- `s#[/_.-]+#-#g`: Replaces 1+ of `/` or `_` or `.` or `-` by a single `-`
- `s/-$//`: Removes trailing `-`
- `s/[A-Z]+/\L&/g`: Lowercase all uppercase substrings

Comment: Note that this only works in GNU sed though.  Not BSD (osx) or Posix

Comment: It is already mentioned in the answer

Answer (score 1):

What I would do in one pass with `awk`:

```
echo "$branch_name" | awk -F '[-_/]' '{OFS="-"}{$0=tolower($0);print $1,$3,$4}'
```

```
abc-kdkd-kdkd
```

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do this using only Bash built-ins. It's commonplace to find scripts that don't use fancy sed or awk regexes to modify strings that use Bash's string manipulation on a line-by-line basis. It's more verbose but it's arguably easier to reason about and debug.

```bash
shopt -s extglob
MODIFIED_BRANCH_NAME=${BRANCH_NAME//['/_.']/-}         # translate illegal characters
MODIFIED_BRANCH_NAME=${MODIFIED_BRANCH_NAME//+(-)/-}   # collapse repeating -
MODIFIED_BRANCH_NAME=${MODIFIED_BRANCH_NAME,,}         # lower-case
MODIFIED_BRANCH_NAME=${MODIFIED_BRANCH_NAME%-}         # trim trailing -
```

However, if your goal for this script is to minimize lines of shell, then you can a `sed`:

```bash
MODIFIED_BRANCH_NAME=$(echo $BRANCH_NAME |
    tr '/_.' '-' |                # translate illegal characters
    tr -s '-' |                   # collapse repeating -
    tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' |  # lower-case
    sed -e 's,-$,,'               # trim trailing -
)
```

Comment: The multiple `tr`s can be reimplemented within the `sed` script using the `y` command.

Comment: Yeah, but a) with pipes you get parallelism for free, and b) I don't know sed all that well. :-)

Comment: Untested; `sed -e 's%[/._]%-%g' -e 's/--*/-/g' -e 'y/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/' -e 's/-$//'`. It's unfortunate that the `y` command doesn't support regex character ranges, but perhaps you could keep a single `tr` if you wanted to keep it succinct.

Comment: The cost of spinning up multiple instances of `tr` is likely much greater than the amount of time it takes to process the few characters in any normal branch name. (I doubt there would be any measurable difference in the time it takes even a single external process to modify the name and the series of separate parameter expansions to do the same.) Parallelism is *not* an argument for using a pipe here.

Answer (score 0):

The literal answer to your question is that you need the string in a variable in order to perform a parameter expansion on that variable. In a pipeline, you are probably looking for a `while read -r` loop:

```
something |
while IFS='' read -r line; do
    echo "${line%-}"
done
```

Notice that besides being verbose and clunky, this will typically be much slower than simply piping to `sed` or Awk or Perl etc. See further [Bash `while read` loop extremely slow compared to `cat`, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762625/bash-while-read-loop-extremely-slow-compared-to-cat-why)

For your concrete problem, I would turn it around and avoid running multiple `tr` commands, but live with the multiple parameter expansions (and then some).

```
MODIFIED_BRANCH_NAME=${BRANCH_NAME//[\/._]/-}
MODIFIED_BRANCH_NAME=${MODIFIED_BRANCH_NAME//--/-}
MODIFIED_BRANCH_NAME=${MODIFIED_BRANCH_NAME,,}
MODIFIED_BRANCH_NAME=${MODIFIED_BRANCH_NAME%-}
```

with no external processes (but clearly more bulky and verbose than you'd like).