# How to filter strings using shell script

Tags: shell

I have a shell script called demo.sh that runs a command and store the output in a variable.

Here is the script:

```
$#!/bin/sh
a=`asterisk -rx "core show hint 101"`
echo "${a}"
```

The output is:

```
101@hints           : SIP/101               State:Unavailable    Presence:not_set         Watchers  0
```

I only need to get the State section, in this case **Unavailable**. This state is not fixed, it changes. I need to get whatever is after **State:** but before **Presence:**

How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bash: shortest way to get n-th column of output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315587/bash-shortest-way-to-get-n-th-column-of-output)

Comment: Write a simple regex to extract the part of string between State and Presence. Use `sed`.

Comment: `a=${a#*State:}; a=${a%%Presence:*}; echo "$a"`

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I resolved the issue with the solution @jhnc provided. Thanks for all guys!