# How to separate columns in linux using awk or cat

Tags: awk, cat

I have a file with 900.000 columns, the structure is:

```
1613 1200000012000500000011111.......
112345 1200000012000500000011111.......
1287659 1200000012000500000011111.......
1234 1200000012000500000011111....... 
712826  1200000012000500000011111.......
```

I need only the numbers before the space, this is a new file as:

```
1613 
112345 
1287659 
1234 
712826
```

I try with

```
cat -df.txt |cut -d |,| -f7
```

but it does not work.

Comment: You could simply do `awk '{print $1}' Input_file` and let me know if this helps you?Considering that you need to print digits before first space in all lines here.

Comment: This might help: [bash: shortest way to get n-th column of output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7315587/3776858)

Comment: you are attempting with cut, using a strange syntax for the delimiter, but also asking for the 7th field...

Comment: The `cut` command you tried is really weird; why would you try to use `|` as f it were a quote character, and whay do you say `-f7` if you don't want the seventh field?

Comment: 900,000 columns or rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of approaches, based on your attempts:

**awk**

As also suggested by [RavinderSingh13](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5866580/ravindersingh13), straightforward [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) approach is

```
awk '{print $1}' yourfile.txt
```

remember `awk` doesn't need `cat`.

**cut**

With vanilla cut as well, this should work:

```
cut -f1 -d' ' yourfile.txt
```

Here you require `cut` to print the first field `-f1` where the delimiter is a whitespace `-d' '`. Remember also `cut` doesn't need `cat` (unlike me always forgetting).

Other very nice approaches with grep and sed can be found in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98983/using-sed-awk-to-remove-anything-after-first-space)