# How to get value after space in string with sed or awk?

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have string lists:

```
./index.blade.php core/resources/views/admin/pages/setting/index.blade.php
./country-flag vendor/country-flag
```

I want to fetch only string after space, how should i write it in sed or awk?

I tried this but it didn't work

```
echo "./country-flag vendor/country-flag"  | awk '/^[[blank]]/{p=1}p'
```

Expected output:

```
vendor/country-flag
```

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts, could you please do mention your expected output in your question, thank you.

Comment: maybe this `echo "./country-flag vendor/country-flag" | sed 's/.* //'`

Comment: @VishalSingh good job.. thanks brother

Comment: how about `cut -d' ' -f2`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bash: shortest way to get n-th column of output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315587/bash-shortest-way-to-get-n-th-column-of-output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Vishal Singh, this sed solution is most terse

```sh
echo "./country-flag vendor/country-flag" | sed 's/.* //'
```

```
vendor/country-flag
```

You could also use grep

```sh
echo "./country-flag vendor/country-flag" | grep -Po '\b[^ ]+$'
```

```
vendor/country-flag
```

The grep options say: using perl `-P` print the matching part only `o`

The regular expression says:
after word boundary `\b` match anything that isn't space `[^ ]` one or more times `+` before the end of the line `$`

Answer (score 4):

By default the field seperator in `awk` is `space`, so we can refer the second field after the space with the help of `$2`

```
echo "./country-flag vendor/country-flag"  |  awk '{print $2}'
```

---

```
vendor/country-flag
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to explain why

```
echo "./country-flag vendor/country-flag"  | awk '/^[[blank]]/{p=1}p'
```

failed to yield desired result. Firstly [bracket expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Bracket-Expressions.html) in `awk` have form of `[:name:]` so it should be `[[:blank:]]` not `[[blank]]`. Secondly after changing your `awk` code to `/^[[:blank:]]/{p=1}p` it will be testing if line starts with blank (space or tab). If so set `p` to `1`. As printing of line depends on value of `p` it will print first line starting with space or tab and *all* following lines, as `p` value is never changed to anything but `1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$ echo "./country-flag vendor/country-flag"  | awk '/[[:blank:]]/{print $2}'
vendor/country-flag
```

More typical in awk (since it, by default splits on `[[:space:]]` already) is to use the `NF` variable that denotes the number of fields in the current record:

```
$ echo "./country-flag vendor/country-flag"  | awk 'NF>1{print $2}'
vendor/country-flag
```

With `sed` you just delete the first field:

```
echo "./country-flag vendor/country-flag"  | sed -E 's/^[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*//'
```

If you want to print a line with no spaces unmodified but only after the first space if there is one:

```
echo "./country-flag vendor/country-flag
./country-flagvendor/country-flag"  |
sed -E '/^[^[:space:]]*$/n; s/^[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*//'
```

Prints:

```
vendor/country-flag
./country-flagvendor/country-flag
```